# Whats a verb for "making one's thoughts and ideas happen"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

While someone is making an artwork, he is expressing his thoughts in a form that it is understandable by others. What is a verb or phrasal verb for this practice?
Is "actualizing his thoughts" correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your context, one is ***manifesting/demonstrating*** their thoughts in a form understandable by others.

ODO:

> **[manifest](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/manifest)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Show (a quality or feeling) by one's acts or appearance; demonstrate
>
> Very early on, Dunov manifested a great love for music and played the
>   violin.’
>   ‘His fear and anticipation were manifested in the drills
>   that he's been doing with his team.’
>
> **[demonstrate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demonstrate)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **1.1** Show (a feeling or quality) by one's actions:
>   ‘she began to demonstrate a new-found confidence’
>
> ‘Their virtues and social responsibility can be demonstrated through
>   their contributions.’

Comment: Thanks so much. 
Is actualizing also correct in the context of just making something if I don't want to emphasis the understandable part?

Comment: [_Actualize_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/actualize) is slightly different in that it's about turning something conceptual (dream, plan, idea or likewise) into a reality.

Comment: You're welcome, @SahandRezaei! Glad if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah actually that solved all my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for "realize."

Definition of realize.
realized.
realizing.
transitive verb
1
a :  to bring into concrete existence :  accomplish.

Merriam-Webster.com

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **incarnate** e.g. *the artwork incarnates her vision of ______*

Quoting http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incarnate

> late 14c., from Late Latin incarnatus "made flesh,"

> **verb (used with object)**, incarnated, incarnating.
> 4. to put into or represent in a concrete form, as an idea:
> *The building incarnates the architect's latest theories.*
> 5. to be the embodiment or type of:
> *Her latest book incarnates the literature of our day.*
> 6. to embody in flesh; invest with a bodily, especially a human, form:
> *a man who incarnated wisdom and compassion.*